# Access Chart based on [long text] fields

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using Access 2013 and I am trying to create a chart report on one of my reports based on a table. There are about 30 fields in this table. The first field ID is auto number and there is another Customer ID which is set to number, the rest are all "long text" (such as name, review and etc) When I went to the form design and created the chart, at the step which it asked me to choose the fields I need, there were only two available fields - ID and customer ID - available, none of the rest popped up(like the customer name and other stuff)

Is there anything I did wrong? I recall I have made this happen in the old version. And I also realized that there is no pivotchart or table view options in 2013 anymore. Is this because the version thing please/

Thanks, any help and advice will be appreciated.

Comment: What's a chart supposed to show if there's no numbers to aggregate?

Comment: would be purchase power by each customer, and some other related charts

Comment: Then your data source isn't the *Customers*, but a *query* that pulls *purchase power* or whatever other "fact" or "metric" you want to chart. And if you're storing metrics and other aggregatable figures as "long text", you have a terrible data structure to work with; consider storing numbers as numbers, dates as dates, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need more than 255 Characters for fields such as Customer Name? I think you need to change the datatypes of the fields you would like to include in the chart. Think about a field in a chart that used the max of a long text field.

From the MS Office website "In Access web apps, the Long Text field can store up to 2^30-1 bytes"

My guess is that access does not allow Long Text fields to appear in charts because of the most logic use case for charts, which does not involve the possibility of using a field that is THAT big.

Anyway, try fitting your data in short text fields. If that is too small, then here is a link to increase the size of your short text fields to [4000](http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-1877873/change-default-short-text-length-access-2013.html)

Comment: I think you named the problem right now! I changed the field to short text and it showed up in the available field. Thanks

Comment: Awesome! Great to hear. I was curious myself, so I tried to make a chart on my own Access DB and I could only see short text.